# When trying to unlock an Android 6 device with fingerprint, the onPasswordFailed() method gets called?

Tags: android, fingerprint, device-admin, android-fingerprint-api

I implemented a receiver which extends **DeviceAdminReceiver** but when the fingerprint unlock fails, the overridden **onPasswordFailed()** method doesn't get called as in other types of unlock. Is this the wanted behaviour?